# Jquery - Select the second Style-Tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can i select the second  Tag?

```
$("head > style:nth-child(2)").html();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html looks like this for example:

```
​<div id="container">
  <span id="span1"></span>
  <span id="span2"></span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Your script:

```
var secondChild = $('div#container > *:eq(1)');
```

​
Where on `eq(n)`: `n` is the zero-based index of the child you want to get. In this case, `1` points to the **second** child of `<div>`.

See more info here: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('head style').eq(1).text()
```

This should do the thing !

Answer (score 0):

... i do not know if this is possible. You cannot select any non-body elements using CSS, so i'm guessing you cannot either using jQuery.

What do you want to do exactly?